# Serial Number Missing From Board

Tags: motherboard, water-damage

I have a problem with my HP ProBook 6570b Notebook laptop. I was drinking a beer and accidentally spilled beer on it. The beer amount wasn't that much, it was just as much as a spoon can take.

I immediately put it upside down but forgot to turn it off so it turned itself off. After this I just put a cold hair dryer on the board, the keyboard and on the board again. I searched on the web and I saw a New York Times post and the post said to keep it upside down for a bare minimum of 4 hours.

I left it 4 hours because I absolutely had some work to do and it did turn on normally but it showed me some weird things like: `Product Serial Number`, `Product SKU`, `Product Family`, `System Board CT Number` and `Enter to continue to startup` but when I "Enter", it shows me `HP Express Boot Options` and after it: `Please Select` and it's a countdown and when I hit `Enter` it freezes.

I don't know what to do. If you guys know anything I thank you for your dedication :)

**Edit New Information:**
I couldn't do anything else because I didn't have the right tools to disassemble my laptop. After opening the laptop case I noticed some beer inside though and I just cleaned it with some dry clothes. I tried to turn it on before letting it for 4 hours and the laptop "turned itself on" while on battery attached and after I removed it didn't do anything else.

Comment: Never tried this on  HP, but Dell laptop with a new (blank) motherboard would do the same. The technician replacing the board would when fill this kind of info once, after which it was read-only.  From the looks if it that it not store in an EPROM but in volatile storage and your beer just short circuited the power to it.

Comment: Also, I hope that you did a lot more than turning it upside down and using a cold hair blower. Including dismantling, cleaning (beer will leave remains) and letting it dry for a few days.

Comment: Hi @Hennes thanks for the comment, well I couldn't do anything else because I didn't have the right tools to disassemble my laptop. After opening the laptop case I noticed some beer inside though and I just cleaned it with some dry clothes. Maybe I should add that I tried to turn it on before letting it for 4 hours and the fact that the laptop "turned himself on" while on battery attached and after I removed it didn't do anything else. I will edit my post again :)

Comment: At this point I would consider priorities. Are you going for data recovery or laptop recovery. If the first, do not plug in power nor battery. Let someone remove the drive and rescue all data from it first.  If you have good backups: congrats. Most people are not until the first disaster.  (Not that loosing just a laptop is not also a disaster, but imagine it holding the sole phots of your firstborn or similar...)